# Encoding error retrieving latin1 N-dash char

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, latin1

I have a MySQL db with a table with latin1 character set.
In a text field there is a '-' N-dash char.

I created a javascript function using XMLHttpRequest() to POST request to a php page that extracts and formats the content of the db; in php I use htmlentities($content, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15') to convert special chars.

When I "call" the php page directly there is not problem and the N-dash char prompt correctly; but when I call the php page with the javascript function and put the result into a `<div>` element, the N-dash char becomes a �.

Where I'm falling?

SOLVED
Googlin for other problems I found the solution: adding

> mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

before sending the query to MySQL.

Comment: Why are you using ISO? That doesn't support Latin characters

Comment: Isn't Latin-1 is ISO-8859-1 ?

Comment: @Cup of Java: there was a moment in wich the "simple" htmlentities($content) returned empty value if $content had some special char. Now I can use it simple widhout problem, but the result of javascript's effect is the same.

Comment: @frz3993: how I sed to Cup of Java, you can forget now that configuration.

Comment: Latin-1 is the same as windows-1252, not ISO-8859-1 or ISO-8859-15.